# memory and efficiency difference between normal array declaration and array declared inside a structure

Tags: c, declaration, performance

When declaring arrays in C they can be declared normally like:

```
int arr[10]
```

or they can also be declared inside a structure like:

```
struct structArr{
   int sArr[10];
}s1;
```

1. Will there be any memory or space tradeoff when using `s1.sArr[]` instead of `arr[]`, if so why?
2. Is any one form more efficient and faster than the other?

What I personally think is that `arr[]` would be faster than `s1.sArr[]` but I don't know whether I am correct or not moreover I don't have a technical answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends upon the compiler and the optimizations.

With a recent GCC compiler with at least `-O1` optimization, `arr[]` won't be faster than `s1.sArr[]`. Actually, if for some reason (e.g. its other fields) `s1` is more aligned than `arr` is, then it could happen (because of cache effects) that `s1.sArr[]` might be slightly better (e.g. because more aligned to cache line size). But really from a performance point of view using `arr[]` or `s1.sArr[]` is (nearly mostly) the same.

For readability reasons things can be different. You may want to pack related items into some `struct`. (And you may want to avoid having too much variable names).

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't expect there to be any difference, no.

The compiler "knows" that the offset of the `sArr` field from the base address of `s1` is 0, so I would guess that accesses can be done using the exact same sequence of instructions.

Of course, wrapping the array in a structure makes it possible to assign and pass/return it by value, which can be nice benefits.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, while the potential performance and memory differences are negligible almost anytime, using this struct indirection thing allows you to determine the size of the array even when passed to a function (no decay to pointer). This can be quite useful.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int arr[10];
} my_arr;

void foo1(my_arr arr) {
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr.arr));
}

void foo2(int arr[10]) {
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr));
}

int main() {
    my_arr a1;
    foo1(a1); /* prints 40 on my machine (10*sizeof(int)) */

    int a2[10];
    foo2(a2); /* prints 8 on my machine (sizeof(int*)) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the difference (if any at all) is worth losing sleep over.

If your example is complete, I would choose `int arr[10];` for readability reasons alone.